# Why is my C++ program crashing as soon as I input a letter or number?

Tags: visual-c++, crash

I start off the program with debugging with a successful build. Then it loads up a screen that says enter a character. I enter a letter. As soon as I press enter the program crashes. Why is this happening? I am running Visual Studio 2015 edition.

Comment: How could we possibly answer this without seeing the code causing the problem, or even the error leading to the crash?

Comment: Try to run the program without debugging. (Ctrl-F5)

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in visual studio (with debugging), the program will execute and the console will automatically kill itself after it's done. The reason it doesn't immediately kill execution is because it is waiting for your input. It is hard to be certain without seeing your code itself, but you are likely not waiting on user input after that initial input. Instead, your program probably just prints something to the console with some intermediary calculations and/or format adjustments. You should add breakpoints if you want to run with debugging, but otherwise I would suggest that you run without debugging if you want to manually close the console.